# Group by with CASE in SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a query like the following how do i group by ?

```
 select distinct
 CTTA.TRANSACTION_TYPE "Transaction Type"
, 'Quota1' "Quota Type"
, CTTA.ATTRIBUTE2 "PO Number"
, (CASE WHEN CTTA.TRANSACTION_TYPE='SFDC'
            THEN CTTA.ATTRIBUTE1
            ELSE CTTA.ATTRIBUTE39
    END
    ) "Customer"
, CTTA.ATTRIBUTE75 "Opportunity Name"
, CTTA.ATTRIBUTE63 "Comm Norm"
, CTTA.ATTRIBUTE8 "Renewal"
,SUM(CTTA.TRANSACTION_AMT_FUNC_CURR) "Transaction Amount"
from xxxxxx
where xxxxxx
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a coherent question here.  Please show us a complete query, or at least enough so that we may get the general idea of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle supports neither positions nor column aliases in `group by`.  You can repeat the the column expressions:

```
 select CTTA.TRANSACTION_TYPE as "Transaction Type"
        'Quota1' as "Quota Type", 
        CTTA.ATTRIBUTE2 "PO Number",
        (CASE WHEN CTTA.TRANSACTION_TYPE='SFDC'
              THEN CTTA.ATTRIBUTE1
              ELSE CTTA.ATTRIBUTE39
         END) as "Customer",
        CTTA.ATTRIBUTE75 as "Opportunity Name",
        CTTA.ATTRIBUTE63 as "Comm Norm",
        CTTA.ATTRIBUTE8 as "Renewal",
        SUM(CTTA.TRANSACTION_AMT_FUNC_CURR) as "Transaction Amount"
from xxxxxx
where xxxxxx
GROUP BY CTTA.TRANSACTION_TYPE, CTTA.ATTRIBUTE2,
         (CASE WHEN CTTA.TRANSACTION_TYPE='SFDC'
               THEN CTTA.ATTRIBUTE1
               ELSE CTTA.ATTRIBUTE39
          END),
         CTTA.ATTRIBUTE75,
         CTTA.ATTRIBUTE63,
         CTTA.ATTRIBUTE75,
         CTTA.ATTRIBUTE8;
```

Comment: Thanks works for me